# I have an error that says: "InvalidCastExceptionWasUnhandled" (VB)

Tags: vb.net

When I run my calculator program than it says InvalidCastExceptionWasUnhandled in the minus sub but I think that nothing wrong, this is the code:

---

Public Class FormCalc

```
Private Sub btnkali_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnkali.Click
    Dim num1 As Double = txtnum1.Text
    Dim num2 As Double = txtnum2.Text
    txthasil.Text = num1 * num2
End Sub

Private Sub btnbagi_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnbagi.Click
    Dim num1 As Double = txtnum1.Text
    Dim num2 As Double = txtnum2.Text
    txthasil.Text = num1 / num2
End Sub

Private Sub btntambah_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btntambah.Click
    Dim num1 As Double = txtnum1.Text
    Dim num2 As Double = txtnum2.Text
    txthasil.Text = num1 + num2
End Sub

Private Sub btnkurang_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnkurang.Click
    Dim num1 As Double = txtnum1.Text
    Dim num2 As Double = txtnum2.Text
    txthasil.Text = num1 - num2
End Sub

Private Sub btnmod_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnmod.Click
    Dim num1 As Double = txtnum1.Text
    Dim num2 As Double = txtnum2.Text
    txthasil.Text = num1 Mod num2
End Sub

Private Sub btnpi_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnpi.Click
    Dim num1 As Double = txtnum1.Text
    Dim num2 As Double = txtnum2.Text
    txthasil.Text = num1 * Math.PI
    txtnum2.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub FormCalc_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

---

It's works fine if i use function but why it cannot run in sub??? can somebody explain it? Thanks! :)

Comment: At what line does it say there is an error? please provide more information if possible

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to identify **exactly** which line is causing the problem, instead of just guessing where it might be and *thinking that nothing's wrong*?

Comment: it highlights this  num2 As Double = txtnum2.Text in this sub: Private Sub btnkurang_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnkurang.Click
    Dim num1 As Double = txtnum1.Text
    Dim num2 As Double = txtnum2.Text
    txthasil.Text = num1 - num2
End Suband says this Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: So it tells you what the problem is - you can't convert `""` to a `Double` (which is true - an empty string cannot be converted to a `Double`, because an empty string is not a number). What more can we tell you?

Comment: why it's work when i just make a function of subtract and call it in the sub?     Private Function kurang(ByVal n1 As Double, ByVal n2 As Double) As Double
        Dim hasil As Double = n1 - n2
        Return hasil
    End Function

Comment: I know where exactly my fault now :'')) thank you Ken White :)))

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that when you convert a string to double you have a number in the string.Check your code. This website is not for debuging your programs!